# Rare Incident when setting dates range in where of a query of MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic, odbc, adodb

I'm programming Classic ASP against a MySql Database connecting with ADODB and MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver, but I have some problems when setting the date in the where of a simple MySql query, when my query is:

```
Select * from cdr where date(calldate)='20170901'
```

The query retrieve data in the asp page, thats ok, but when the query is

```
Select * from cdr where date(calldate) between '20170801' and '20170828'
```

When I print the query and then I copy from html and paste into Mysql Workbench, then it retrieve data, but when in the asp page itself does not retrieve a any data.

Any Ideas? I think maybe is something with de ODBC Driver.

Comment: Try using the format `2017-08-01` to specify your dates. Does it help?

Comment: Ok the problem is not when i put "where date(calldate)='20170901' " the problem is just when I put a range of dates, "where date(calldate) between '20170801' and '20170828' " If I specify '2017-08-01' and '2017-08-31' the problem still happens, or using str_to_date, is the same.

Comment: What datatype is `calldate`?

Comment: @RickJames datetime

Answer (score 6):

If you want use a not mysql default date format   you must convert properly

```
Select * from cdr where date(calldate)=str_to_date('20170901','%Y%m%d')
```

otherwise use the mysql default format

```
Select * from cdr where date(calldate)='2017-09-01'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not trust this format: `'20170801'`

Since `calldate` is `DATETIME`, this would be faster:

```
    WHERE calldate >= '2017-08-01'
      AND calldate  < '2017-08-01' + INTERVAL 28 DAY`.
```

It would require `INDEX(calldate)`

Comment: Nop, Just work with cast(calldate as date) = '20170901' , but if I put cast(calldate as date) >= '20170901'  then it doesn't work.

Comment: Hiding `calldate` inside a function (`CAST`) makes it impossible to use the index for efficiency.